# How to deal with GeoDataFrame object having no attribute explore?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have already reinstalled geopandas, but I still get error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.explore("pop_est", cmap="Blues")

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\GPD\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'explore'
```

The code that I am using is:

```
df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
df.explore("pop_est", cmap="Blues")
```

Thanks!

Comment: what version of geopandas do you have installed? and how did you install it?

Comment: I am using the version 0.9.0.

Comment: `gdf.explore()` was added to geopandas in version 0.10 (Oct 3, 2021). See the [changelog](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/changelog.html#version-0-10-0-october-3-2021). So you'll need to update to get the new features.

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to save the map derived from the gdf.explore() as an html so that it can be accessed without the python?

Comment: explore() returns a follium map, so I think the regular follium API applies. so I think `m.save("mymap.html")` should work - see the [follium quickstart](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html)

Comment: This works. One more question, is it possible to add the dropdown menu to the map so that the heatmap changes based on the selection of the specific column from the geodataframe?

Comment: haha - you're welcome to post new questions! but I can't solve all your follium questions in this thread ;)

Comment: Understood. Will create a menu question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdf.explore()` was added to geopandas in version 0.10 (Oct 3, 2021). See the [changelog](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/changelog.html#version-0-10-0-october-3-2021). So to be able to use explore, you'll need to update, e.g.:

```bash
pip install --upgrade geopandas
```

or

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas>=0.10.0
```